# what is the best ORM for C#.NET in my business

Tags: c#, orm, ibatis.net

I build a framework that is for high traffic site, the site only for other application site log records.

I used redis or file in the middle layer to cache log
In a certain period of time, the program will take cache into the database.

Because there is a large amount of data, I need a ORM what is lightweight and agile .

I use Mysql5.x, because the SQL server of the relatively high price.

I am more familiar with ibatis (for Java),but ibatis.net was not update for two years, so, ibatis.net whether can meet the requirements?

if ibatis can do it,I can reduce a lot of learning time.
Or are you any better suggestions?

c#'s new technology, I am not very familiar with, please pointing

Comment: This is primarily opinion based !

Comment: The use of simple, easy maintenance, can optimize the SQL statement,just like ibatis.

Comment: As developers we lean heavily on opinions of other devs. I don't understand why Stackoverflow plays god and kills all questions where an opinion is asked.

Wouldn't it be better to let these questions be asked, then the community could then  upvote popular opinions and downvote unpopular ones.  

Win-Win for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything high performance, I use [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net). It's a micro-ORM with very high performance developed and used by the very website your are seeing! (stackoverflow.com).

It has a NuGet package too, which you can install by `Install-Package Dapper` command in package manager console.

Comment: ok，i will see the document for Dapper.

Comment: sqlkata is my favor